# OCR Time stamp extraction with complex background

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract

Here is an image cut from CCTV video and I would like to extract the time stamp from the snapshot. OpenCV/Tesseract/python are the tools for this job:
[image: a cctv snapshot with complex background]

the difficulty here is the complex background so that even I binarize the picture with a median filer (opencv) and the ocr result is still very bad. Of course, I can apply specific customized thresholds but here I got 2 issues:

1. how can I handle the characters with both white and black?
2. Is there a way (some ways) to give a more general thresholds for these kinds of picture?

Maybe my idea for handling the pre-processing here is not correct. It seems not an easy job to pre-process this kind of image before sending into Tesseract. Any hints and idea is thankful.

Comment: mask the image for only white(255) and black(0) pixels. then see the results.

Comment: Could you post the code sample you used to perform the OCR?

Answer (score 2):

1. Do the tresholding two times, once normally for white pixels above 254, and once on a inverted picture: `img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)` , then merge the two results
2. There is an [inRange](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html) function in OpenCV, where you can set min/max HSV values. Create a function with this with input arguments of the HSV values, record the values in lists, then iterate with a `for` cycle the masking+merging